# Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement, variables in sql statements

Tags: python, sql

I am trying to do something with SQL for my school project. To use variables in the SQL statements I followed this post: [How to use variables in SQL statement in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/902408/how-to-use-variables-in-sql-statement-in-python).
But I am getting the following error in this function:

> Something went wrong: Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement

```
def Einkauf():
Typ = int(input("Typ"))
Anzahl = input("Anzahl")
MHD = input("MHD (YYYYMMDD)")
try:
    cursor.execute("insert into Warenlager(Anzahl, MHD, StatusID, TypId) values(?,?,1,?)", (Anzahl,MHD,Typ))
    db.commit()
except mysql.connector.Error as err:
    print("Something went wrong: {}".format(err))
```

Comment: What database are you using? Some adapters use `%s` fur the placeholder rather than `?`.

Comment: i am using mysql with phpmyadmin as websurface. The modules i am using are mysql.connector and sqlite3 to make the '?' work. In the post i am referencing in the way with '%s' is called insecure.

Comment: You can't be using mysql.connector *and* sqlite. Sqlite is a completely different database. You are using MySQL, which as I say uses `%s`.

Answer (score 1):

As I said in the comments, mysql.connector uses `%s` as the placeholder.

```
cursor.execute("insert into Warenlager(Anzahl, MHD, StatusID, TypId) values(%s, %s, 1, %s)", (Anzahl,MHD,Typ))
```

Note, this is *not* insecure, because you are not using that for string interpolation. This *would* be insecure:

```
cursor.execute("insert into Warenlager(Anzahl, MHD, StatusID, TypId) values(%s, %s, 1, %s)" % (Anzahl,MHD,Typ))  # don't do this
```

In fact, the post you reference says exactly the same thing, so I don't know where you got the idea that you shouldn't do it.

Answer (score -1):

change this

```
Warenlager(Anzahl, MHD, StatusID, TypId) values(?,?,1,?)", (Anzahl,MHD,Typ)
```

to

```
Warenlager(Anzahl, MHD, StatusID, TypId) values(?,?,?,?)", (Anzahl,MHD,1,Typ)
```